# Laravel Query how to check if column starts with 0

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a CRUD application with a `Registration` table and a `Category` table. In the `RegistrationController`, I use a query with Category, so I have made another query. I struggled with checking if every other `gender_id` has a `cte_from` that starts with 0. The `cte_gender_id` has 1, 2, or 3. 1 = man, 2 = women 3 = undetermined and nd `cte_from` are age ranges.

So in the database: `cte_gender_id` is 1 and `cte_from` is 0
then anther row `cte_gender_id` is 1 and `cte_from` is 25
then another `cte_gender_id` is 1 and 35
and so on but with `gender_id` 2 and 3.

**RegistrationController**

```
$gender_ids = ['1', '2', '3'];
foreach ($gender_ids as $gender_id) {
    $category = Categorie::where('cte_distance_id', $distance_id)
        ->where('cte_gender_id', $gender_id)
        ->where('cte_from',)
        ->first();
    
    if (is_null($category)) {
        return back()->with("errorMessage", "Category not found");
    }
}
```

So I want if, for example, where gender_id is 1 and cte_from doesn't start with 0, it already doesn't go through.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `WHERE cte_from LIKE '0%'` to test if a string starts with `0`.
 In this query, `%` is used for a wildcard.

Or in Laravel query builder:

```
->where('cte_from', 'LIKE', '0%')

// Or if it doesn't start with a 0
->where('cte_from', 'NOT LIKE', '0%')
```